# How to construct a ParseIntError in my own code?

Tags: error-handling, rust, code-reuse

I want to reuse the standard library's [`ParseIntError`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/struct.ParseIntError.html) in my function. However, I'm implementing parsing of the input string myself, so I don't need to return an error value returned by the standard library.

I didn't find a way to construct `ParseIntError` value. The only solution I found looks like this:

```
use std::num::ParseIntError;

fn from_str_radix(s: &str, radix: u32) -> Result<(), ParseIntError> {
    let error_empty = "".parse::<i32>().expect_err("get empty input error");
    let error_invalid_digit = "Z".parse::<i32>().expect_err("get invalid digit error");

    if s.is_empty() {
        return Err(error_empty);
    }

    for c in s.chars().rev() {
        match c.to_digit(radix) {
            None => return Err(error_invalid_digit),
            _ => unimplemented!(),
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Is there more elegant way to return `ParseIntError` from my own code?

Comment: If you want do you own parsing, why don't you want your own error type ? `ParseIntError` doesn't impl public constructor and its field are private. So you can't

Comment: I see. But as far as I see it's usual practice to reuse this error value if std parsing is used. I don't see why should I switch to my own type just because I changed my internal implementation from calling library function to own parsing

Comment: without [mcve], I can't answer, you claim "I'm implementing parsing of input string myself", you never said "I changed my internal implementation from calling library function to own parsing" in your question, so please [edit] your question to include an [mcve], and be more accurate about what you want and what you do

Comment: You could provoke the same error and then return that, e.g. `"a".parse::<i32>()?` (dont' take this serious)

Comment: @Stargateur here is request to fix this issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1143. Unfortunately it's open since 2015 and seems no one cares about it :-(

Comment: I don't think it's would be a good thing to do, maybe you could use nightly feature, https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=43c2a9bce39c5ccd1120a36edceefbad. Still waiting my [mcve]

Comment: @Stargateur Thank you for this 'int_error_matching' feature. It's not a solution but at least some approach to it.
Example - I don't think it's necessary here. The situation is already clear enough: I can't create ParseIntError myself but can reuse nightly IntErrorKind for my own error type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently no way to construct a [`ParseIntError`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/struct.ParseIntError.html) yourself. As you find it, there is an open [`issue`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1143) that asks to make it public. However, I don't think it's a good idea.

`ParseIntError` is the error of `num` module. It isn't made to be used by everyone that would implement a parsing crate because you **should** have your own potential error. You could use [`IntErrorKind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/num/enum.IntErrorKind.html) but I still don't think is a good thing because you could end by not having the same error.

So, I think you should have your own error type, and maybe use the same design, have an `enum` with `#[non_exhaustive]` attribute. You should not hesitate to use your own error in your own code. See very good article [Error Handling In Rust - A Deep Dive](https://www.lpalmieri.com/posts/error-handling-rust/). (I personally doesn't agree with everything in the article but that still high quality, I recommend using [snafu](https://crates.io/crates/snafu) or [thiserror](https://crates.io/crates/thiserror))

Comment: Isn't there value in making it constructable for testing purposes?

Comment: @WilliamHammond can `kind()` and match with `IntErrorKind` if you realty need to. Or just `is_err()`.

Comment: As of May 2021, both IntErrorKind and ParseIntError seem to be marked as public.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/struct.ParseIntError.html

Comment: @dagilpe no the situation didn't change, there is still no way to **create** a ParseIntError yourself.

Comment: Any news on this? I just stumbled over this when writing a doctest:
`assert_eq!(num, Err(StrParseError::<i8, i8>::InvalidRealPart(ParseIntError{ kind: IntErrorKind::InvalidDigit })));`

Comment: @RichardNeumann didn't change I still recommend use your own error type, I added resource to read to learn.